# Unable to find and element in selenium using name

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to fine the element by name.

The code is simple I have mentioned below

```
WebElement FirstName = driver.findElement(By.name("anyname"));
FirstName.sendKeys("xyz");
```

I get the following error

> Unable to find element with name == txtVFNAME (WARNING: The server did
>   not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout:
>   282 milliseconds

Is there a way to locate the element by DOM?
Also can I use some sort of loop which will help me in the visibility if this element?

Comment: can you provide the source html for this element? did u also try with webdriver wait

Comment: none of these works, i have tried both

Answer (score 0):

You can find all needed elements using `findElements`

```
List<WebElement> inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@name='Your_name']"));

for (var element=0; element < inputs.size(); element ++){
    if( inputs[element].isDisplayed()){
         //your code
    }
}
```

In this case `//*[@name='Your_name']` you are searching on attribute name. For more xpath cases take a look on [cheat sheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html)

Comment: i am using IE. i don't want to use xpath.

Comment: alright, how about driver.findElements(By.cssSelector ("[name='YOUR_NAME']"))

Comment: okay, last try - driver.findElements(By.cssSelector ("#YOUR_ID[name='YOUR_NAME']"))

Comment: i am getting length cannot be resolved or is not a field

Answer (score 0):

Your question is clear but the data your provided is not enough to help. I believe the element you are looking is might be in iframe or hidden. Please provide the source code of the webpage you testing.

Comment: it is not in iframe.
Code is soemthing like
<INPUT tabIndex=2 onkeypress=javascript:UCFirstOnKeyPress(this); onblur=javascript:RemoveUnwantedCharacters(this);UCFirstOnBlur(this); id=Anyname onkeydown='CallRestricted("Anyname")' style="WIDTH: 150px" maxLength=35 name=anyname>

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to locate the element by DOM?

Open a Firefox browser. Launch the URL and Firebug. There should be search box where you can search for "txtVFNAME".